# FFT spectrogram in python

Tags: python, fft

I have python 3.4.

I transmitted a 2MHz (for example) frequency and received the cavitation over the time (until I stopped the measurement).
I want to get a spectrogram (cavitation vs frequency) and more interesting is a spectrogram of cavitation over the time of the sub-harmonic (1MHz) frequency.

The data is saved in sdataA (=cavitation), and t (=measurement time)

I tried to save fft in FFTA

```
FFTA = np.array([])
FFTA = np.fft.fft(dataA)
FFTA = np.append(FFTA, dataA)
```

I got real and complex numbers
Then I took only half (from 0 to 1MHz) and save the real and complex data.

```
nA = int(len(FFTA)/2)
yAre = FFTA[range(nA)].real
yAim = FFTA[range(nA)].imag
```

I tried to get the frequencies by:

```
FFTAfreqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(yAre))
```

But it is totally wrong (I printed the data by `print (FFTAfreqs)`)

I also plotted the data and again it's wrong:

```
plt.plot(t, FFTA[range(n)].real, 'b-', t, FFTA[range(n)].imag, 'r--')
plt.legend(('real', 'imaginary'))
plt.show()
```

How can I output a spectrogram of cavitation over the time of the sub-harmonic (1MHz) frequency?

**EDIT:**

Data example:

see a sample of 'dataA' and 'time':

```
dataA = [6.08E-04,2.78E-04,3.64E-04,3.64E-04,4.37E-04,4.09E-04,4.49E-04,4.09E-04,3.52E-04,3.24E-04,3.92E-04,3.24E-04,2.67E-04,3.24E-04,2.95E-04,2.95E-04,4.94E-04,4.09E-04,3.64E-04,3.07E-04]
time = [0.00E+00,4.96E-07,9.92E-07,1.49E-06,1.98E-06,2.48E-06,2.98E-06,3.47E-06,3.97E-06,4.46E-06,4.96E-06,5.46E-06,5.95E-06,6.45E-06,6.94E-06,7.44E-06,7.94E-06,8.43E-06,8.93E-06,9.42E-06]
```

**EDIT II:**
From @Martin example I tried the following code, please let me know if I did it right.

In the case that dataA and Time are saved as h5 files (or the data that I posted already)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dfdata = pd.read_hdf("C:\\data_python\\DataA.h5")
dft = pd.read_hdf("C:\\data_python\\time.h5")
dft_cor = int((len(dft)-2)*4.96E-6)   # calculating the measured time

fs = 2000000 #sampling frequency 2MHz
CHUNK = 10000
signal_time = dft_cor # seconds

def sine(freq,fs,secs):
    data=dfdata
    wave = np.sin(freq*2*np.pi*data)
    return wave

a1 = sine(fs,fs,120)
a2 = sine(fs/2,fs,120)

signal = a1+a2
afft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal[0:CHUNK]))
freqs = np.linspace(0,fs,CHUNK)[0:int(fs/2)]
spectrogram_chunk = freqs/np.amax(freqs*1.0)

# Plot spectral analysis
plt.plot(freqs[0:1000000],afft[0:1000000]) # 0-1MHz
plt.show()

number_of_chunks = 1000

# Empty spectrogram
Spectrogram = np.zeros(shape = [CHUNK,number_of_chunks])

for i in range(number_of_chunks):
    afft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal[i*CHUNK:(1+i)*CHUNK]))
    freqs = np.linspace(0,fs,CHUNK)[0:int(fs/2)]
    spectrogram_chunk = afft/np.amax(afft*1.0)
    try:
        Spectrogram[:,i]=spectrogram_chunk
    except:
        break


import cv2
Spectrogram = Spectrogram[0:1000000,:]
cv2.imshow('spectrogram',np.uint8(255*Spectrogram/np.amax(Spectrogram)))
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How is wrong? What did you get and what do you expect? If you could post a minimum sample of your data, that could help to replicate the issue

Comment: What could be going on is that you are performing your transform over the wrong axis of your data. As @gustavovelascoh said, please post some sample of 'dataA' so we can better help you.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh please see a sample of 'dataA' and 'time'            
dataA: 6.08E-04 2.78E-04 3.64E-04 3.64E-04 4.37E-04 4.09E-04 4.49E-04 4.09E-04 3.52E-04 3.24E-04 3.92E-04 3.24E-04 2.67E-04 3.24E-04 2.95E-04 2.95E-04 4.94E-04 4.09E-04 3.64E-04 3.07E-04                                              
time: 0.00E+00 4.96E-07 9.92E-07 1.49E-06 1.98E-06 2.48E-06 2.98E-06 3.47E-06 3.97E-06 4.46E-06 4.96E-06 5.46E-06 5.95E-06 6.45E-06 6.94E-06 7.44E-06 7.94E-06 8.43E-06 8.93E-06 9.42E-06

Comment: I edited the answer with the data you shared. I followed the code you posted and got this: https://imgur.com/mng3Z7n. Why don't plot magnitude instead of real and img?. With this, and as stated by @martin, you need to get intervals of time to generate each column in the image of the spectrogram.

Comment: @don Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Martin I edited the post (EDIT II) with code that I took from your example. Did I understand right? (case of 2MHz, I care only about 1MHz)

Comment: @don I cant help you with this. My example works but I dont know your data. All i can do is to try it on your data, otherwise I cant help anymore. So if you can, give me link to data.

Comment: @don would you like me to test it on your data?

Answer (score 8):

It seems your problem is not in Python but in understanding what is Spectrogram.

---

Spectrogram is **sequences** of spectral analysis of a signal.

1) You need to cut your signal in CHUNKS.

2) Do spectral analysis of these CHUNKS and stick it together.

**Example:**

You have 1 second of audio recoding (44100 HZ sampling). That means the recording will have 1s * 44100 -> 44100 samples.  You define CHUNK size = 1024 (for example).

For each chunk you will do FFT, and stick it together into 2D matrix (X axis - FFT of the CHUNK, Y axis -  CHUNK number,). 44100 samples / CHUNK ~ 44 FFTs, each of the FFT covers 1024/44100~0.023 seconds of the signal

**The bigger the CHUNK**, the more accurate Spectrogram is, but less 'realtime'.

**The smaller the CHUNK is,** the less acurate is the Spectrogram, but you have more measurements as you measure frequencies 'more often'.

If you need 1MHZ - actually you cannot use anything higher than 1MHZ, you just take half of the resulting FFT array - and it doesnt matter which half, because 1MHZ is just the half of your sampling frequency, and the FFT is mirroring anything that is higher than 1/2 of sampling frequency.

---

**About FFT, you dont want complex numbers. You want to do**

FFT = np.abs(FFT) # Edit - I just noticed you use '.real', but I will keep it here

because you want real numbers.

**Preparation for Spectrogram** - example of Spectrogram

Audio Signal with 150HZ wave and 300HZ Wave

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fs = 44100#sampling frequency
CHUNK = 10000
signal_time = 20 # seconds

def sine(freq,fs,secs):
    data=np.arange(fs*secs)/(fs*1.0)
    wave = np.sin(freq*2*np.pi*data)
    return wave

a1 = sine(150,fs,120)
a2 = sine(300,fs,120)

signal = a1+a2
afft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal[0:CHUNK]))
freqs = np.linspace(0,fs,CHUNK)[0:int(fs/2)]
spectrogram_chunk = freqs/np.amax(freqs*1.0)

# Plot spectral analysis
plt.plot(freqs[0:250],afft[0:250])
plt.show()

number_of_chunks = 1000

# Empty spectrogram
Spectrogram = np.zeros(shape = [CHUNK,number_of_chunks])

for i in range(number_of_chunks):
    afft = np.abs(np.fft.fft(signal[i*CHUNK:(1+i)*CHUNK]))
    freqs = np.linspace(0,fs,CHUNK)[0:int(fs/2)]
    #plt.plot(spectrogram_chunk[0:250],afft[0:250])
    #plt.show()
    spectrogram_chunk = afft/np.amax(afft*1.0)
    #print(signal[i*CHUNK:(1+i)*CHUNK].shape)
    try:
        Spectrogram[:,i]=spectrogram_chunk
    except:
        break


import cv2
Spectrogram = Spectrogram[0:250,:]
cv2.imshow('spectrogram',np.uint8(255*Spectrogram/np.amax(Spectrogram)))
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Spectral analysis of single CHUNK**

[image: Spectral analysis of single CHUNK]

**Spectrogram**

[image: Spectrogram]

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I will try it. I add part of the dataA: 6.08E-04
2.78E-04
3.64E-04
3.64E-04
4.37E-04
4.09E-04
4.49E-04
4.09E-04
3.52E-04
3.24E-04
3.92E-04
3.24E-04
2.67E-04
3.24E-04
2.95E-04
2.95E-04
4.94E-04
4.09E-04
3.64E-04
3.07E-04

and time:                                                          
0.00E+00
4.96E-07
9.92E-07
1.49E-06
1.98E-06
2.48E-06
2.98E-06
3.47E-06
3.97E-06
4.46E-06
4.96E-06
5.46E-06
5.95E-06
6.45E-06
6.94E-06
7.44E-06
7.94E-06
8.43E-06
8.93E-06
9.42E-06

Comment: I try to run first your example to understand what exactly you did, I get an error by using cv2.                                                                                       
OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:261: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
Unsupported depth of input image:
'VDepth::contains(depth)'
where
'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)

Comment: @don Try now. If it doesnt work, tell me on which line is the error

Comment: I will check it now and I will update soon, thank you.

Comment: I tried what you posted, I didn't get any error anymore but imshow window (spectrogram) is black [link](https://imgur.com/a/OqzQPBv)

Comment: @don your picture is exactly the correct output. Its black with 2 white lines signifying 150Hz and 300Hz. I will edit the image in my answer